# Retrieve the name of a mobile network interface even when not activated

Tags: c#, windows, network-interface

I would like to know how I could retrieve (preferably with a C# API) the name of a mobile interface **even when it has been disabled**.

The last statement is important because because the most obvious (and cleanest) solutions I know don't work with disabled interfaces.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. **System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface**

   `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` ***only*** returns **enabled** interfaces.
2. **WMI query on `Win32_NetworkAdapter`**

   Almost the same problem in this case. Let's consider the following query

   ```
   new ManagementObjectSearcher(
        "SELECT NetConnectionID FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter Where AdapterTypeId=9"
   ).Get()
   ```

   The interface name corresponds to the `NetConnectionID` and an `AdapterTypeId` = 9 corresponds to a wireless one so the query hereabove should give me what I want...except that when the interface is not enabled, the value of `AdapterTypeId` is left empty and the query doesn't return anything. It is a pity because `NetConnectionID` is still correct but I don't have any criteria to retrieve it. (A join maybe...?)
3. **Shell command**

   Same issue.

   ```
   netsh mbn show interfaces
   ```

   ...which returns on a target machine

   ```
   Le système dispose d'1 interface :

   Nom                   : Cellulaire
   Description            : Sierra Wireless Mobile Broadband Network Adapter
   GUID                   : {AAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAA}
   Adresse physique       : 00:00:00:00:00:00
   Contexte PDP supplémentaire : non (interface physique)
   ...
   ```

   ...when the interface is **enabled only**! Again!

   Furthermore he response is language dependent (in French here) so the parsing is IMHO more fragile and complicated since it is highly probable that some machines are configured in another language.

   I'd rather avoid this kind of solution which can might work with one configuration and fail with another one.

**Note**: the machines where it is supposed to work run on Windows 7 and Windows 10

Comment: To the person who  voted to close this question, please read it again: I don't see what could make you think I am looking for any book or library recommandation. I just want to solve a specific problem and I enumerate what I have already tried without success.